# Pass upload image to Codeigniter 3 security function

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to use this security function in my controller in Codeigniter 3 in order to upload images in the uploads folder.

```
if ($this->security->xss_clean($_FILES, TRUE) === FALSE){
     // file failed the XSS test
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    die('The file you requested is not an image.');
}else{
   //the file is an image we can go on
}
```

I have changed some pdf file extension to .jpg and when I upload the fake image the script don't stops the execution.

So I have tried to pass $_FILES, $_FILES['userFile'], $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] but all with the same result.

My question is, which is the correct parameter I have to pass to this security function?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [PHP Image Upload Security: How Not to Do It](http://nullcandy.com/php-image-upload-security-how-not-to-do-it/)

Comment: [Codeigniter: Validating File Uploads](http://keighl.com/post/codeigniter-file-upload-validation/)

Comment: @SpYk3HH, thanks for your reply, but I have already visited those links. From the first one I already took the advice to use the .htaccess file. In the second this statement if (isset($_FILES['image']) && !empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) only ensure that you have something passed but do not check if this is really an image. My goal is to use the function I have mentioned in my question. What I need to know is what has to be passed in it as parameter.

Comment: [exif_imagetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)

Comment: `if (exif_imagetype('image.gif') != IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
    echo 'The picture is not a gif';
}`

Comment: This is not working because I need to pass the image path too and I don't have it. The uploaded image resides on someone computer before uploading. I can also not use the Codeigniter uploader library because i am using Intervention Image. As I sad I only need to use the above mentioned function and pass the proper parameter to it. So I am looking for this parameter.

Comment: then you'll have to get creative and write your own validation method, however, you could still make use of the above in combo. Get given path, look up type to test against, then test it. Simply throw a `switch case` in your method.